# How to handle this exception in asp.net 3-tier application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, 3-tier

I am a new ASP.net developer and I am trying to do add proper exception handling in my simple 3-tier web-based application. By following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113277/exception-handling-in-n-tier-applications), I have done, for example, the following in the Data Access Layer (DAL) and the User Interface (UI):

**DAL:**

```
public IEnumerable<Survey> getData()
{
    List<Survey> surveysList = new List<Survey>();
    try
    {
        using (ItemsDBEntities context = new ItemsDBEntities())
        {
            surveysList = (from survey in context.Surveys
                         select new Survey()
                         {
                             ID = survey.ID,
                             startDate = survey.StartDate,
                             EndDate = survey.EndDate,
                             Description = survey.Description
                         }).ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (EntityException ex)
    {
        //something wrong about entity
        throw new ConnectionFailedException(ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Don't know what happend... 
    }
    return surveysList;
}
```

**Code-Behind of UI:**

```
private void bindGrid()
{
    Survey survey = new Survey();
    try
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = survey.getData();
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.Visible = true;
    }
    catch (ConnectionFailedException)
    {
        Label1.Text = "There was a problem accessing the database, please try again.";
    }
}
```

However, I am still getting a red line under

> ConnectionFailedException

in each tier and I don't know why, and it gave me the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'ConnectionFailedException' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)TestWebsite\App_Code\DAL\Survey.cs

**How can I fix this thing?** I don't want to create a class for each exception type that I am going to throw it like what I have done so far. 
Could you please provide me with a help and example if possible?

Comment: Is the assembly that contains `ConnectionFailedException` referenced in your project? If so, do you have the appropriate `using` directives? Also, a note on exceptions: Don't catch an exception and do nothing (e.g. an empty catch block). If you can't handle the exception, let it bubble up until something that *can* handle it catches it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added `Microsoft.Rfid.SpiSdk` assembly reference OR `Dll` might be missed in the build

```
Namespace: Microsoft.SensorServices.Rfid.Dspi
Assembly: Microsoft.Rfid.SpiSdk (in microsoft.rfid.spisdk.dll)
```

Comment: I don't think I am throwing the right exception. What do you think?

Comment: @user3107976: Error is clearing saying that "....'ConnectionFailedException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference..."